# BASH. Sourcing local script on remote host on login

Tags: bash

I have a local bash script with some useful functions I use frequently.
Is there any way to source this file on a remote host on login?

Let's say, the name of the local file with functions **helper.sh**, it has **test()** function that just outputs "test msg"

```
localhost$ ls
helper.sh
localhost$. ./helper.sh
localhost$test
test msg
```

I log in to a remote host and want my **test()** function from the **helper.sh** working on the remote host without copying **helper.sh** onto the remote host in advance:

```
localhost$ ssh user@remotehost  # or something else to make my script work on  remote host
remotehost$ test
test msg
```

Comment: i use [tag:expect]-like tools for this.

Comment: i also use the `$TERM` tricks mentioned in https://superuser.com/questions/163167/

Answer (score 0):

I have a special function for this:

```
function ssh_with_rcfile
{
    if (( $# == 1 )); then
        local remote_hostname=$(echo ${1:?Need remote hostname} | sed 's/^[^@]*@//')  # always rsync as default user
        rsync --quiet \
            $LINUX_CONFIG_DIR/.sshrc \
            $LINUX_CONFIG_DIR/some_other_file.sh \
            $remote_hostname:/tmp/${USER}/
        /usr/bin/ssh -t $1 "bash --rcfile /tmp/${USER}/.sshrc -i"
    else
        # TODO: This is not very useful, probably better to just append any remaining arguments to the ssh command above
        /usr/bin/ssh "$@"
    fi
}
```

`ssh -t` combined with the remote `bash --rcfile` command allows you to effectively source a remote file upon login.  So I just rsync my `.sshrc` file up to the remote before logging in.

One caveat is that you can only have a single `rcfile`, so if you want to source multiple files (e.g. `some_other_file.sh` above), you have to handle them all from inside of `.sshrc`.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh user@server './test/file.sh'`

The command logs you in with a command to be run, in this example which is to run the file.sh

The backticks are used to run the command on the remote machine, and then pass the output to your local machine, as if you entered the command on the local machine.

Comment: I suppose it just executes `./test/file.sh` output on the remote host and logs out immediately after that. this is not what I need.